# Is this the only DRY way to manipulate subtype collections?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, dry

In a project, I've got a set of classes that implement an abstract base class...

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Property { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : BaseClass

public class Bar : BaseClass

/*etc*/
```

...and for another class I need to perform some manipulations on them in a collection. The only things that need manipulated are members of the base class. Because of the collections, it's kind of repetitive to write one method for each type, and I feel like I'm missing something. Here's what I have so far:

```
public ICollection<BaseClass> Transform(ICollection<BaseClass> source, Guid newId, Func<BaseClass> factory)
{
    ICollection<BaseClass> result = new List<BaseClass>();

    foreach (BaseClass x in source)
    {
        BaseClass record = factory();

        record.Id = newId;
        record.Name = x.Name;
        record.Property = x.Property;

        result.Add(record);
    }

    return result;
}

public ICollection<Foo> TransformFoos(ICollection<Foo> source, string property)
{
    Func<BaseClass> factory = () => new Foo();
    ICollection<BaseClass> sourceAsBase = source.Select(x => (BaseClass)x).ToList();
    ICollection<Foo> result = this.Transform(sourceAsBase, property, factory)
                                  .Select(x => (Foo)x)
                                  .ToList();
    return result;
}

public ICollection<Bar> TransformBars(ICollection<Bar> source, string property)

/*etc*/
```

This is a **LOT** of transformation, though. Is there a better way?

Comment: What is your end goal? right now it looks like you are just copying the list. Btw; `sourceAsBase` isn't even used. I would think a single `Select` would work but I would need to know the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I'd mistyped.

In context, this is going to be used as part of a save-as operation to copy an EF object's navigation properties, and these navigation properties themselves are collections of `Foo`, `Bar`, etc. Rather than update all of them to have the new object's key data (partly because I don't want EF to mark the source object's properties as modified), I'm creating them as new collections.

Comment: I also updated the code to update the `Id` property, which is what I'm actually doing in the live code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much any time you see code that's doing exactly the same thing but with a different type it means you should be using generics.  Here you can simply make your transformation method generic, constrain it to base class types, and you're all set.

```
public List<T> Transform<T>(IEnumerable<BaseClass> source, string property)
    where T : BaseClass, new()
{
    return source.Select(sourceItem => new T()
    {
        Id = sourceItem.Id,
        Name = sourceItem.Name,
        Property = property,
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with this one, and it works beautifully! My only change was to update `source` to be `ICollection<T>`, which also alleviated the need to specify the type when calling the method! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update properties defined on SubTypes you can use pattern matching the new C# feature instead of writing separate method of each SubType.

```
    switch(x)
    {
        case Foo f:
            f.Foo1 = "Updated foo";
        break;
        case Bar b:
            b.Bar1 = "Updated bar";
        break;
    }
```

Below is you update method with the same.

```
public static ICollection<BaseClass> Transform(ICollection<BaseClass> source, string property, Func<BaseClass> factory)
{
    ICollection<BaseClass> result = new List<BaseClass>();

    foreach (BaseClass x in source)
    {
        BaseClass record = factory();

        record.Id = x.Id;
        record.Name = x.Name;
        record.Property = property;

        result.Add(record);

        switch(x)
        {
            case Foo f:
                f.Foo1 = "Updated foo";
            break;
            case Bar b:
                b.Bar1 = "Updated bar";
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```